# How to Collapse submenu on clicking arrow?

Tags: wordpress, megamenu

I am using max mega menu wordpress plugin for implementing menu. Desktop view is working fine but in mobile view it is not expanding on clicking arrow. I tried multiple option and script to work but not found any thing relevant to it.

You can check below link-

https://bit73.mydevfactory.com/goutam/spinwell/

Answer (score 0):

With the free version of this plugin, under Mega Menu -> Mega Locations, select the menu you want to edit, click Advanced, and try out the options under Click Event Behavior.
https://www.megamenu.com/documentation/mobile-menu/#click-event-on-mobile

Comment: Used already but no effect

Comment: Are there any updated waiting for the plugin?
There are some JS console errors that you'd need to look at too, in case those are interfering with that Mega Menu option. And if you haven't already, make sure any custom scripts you tried for this are completely removed or commented out.

Comment: i tried but no effect...can you give me a good help